# Cannot create azure private dns A record with its ip by using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-dns

I am trying to create an A record in an Azure private DNS Zone with an `ARM template`. The creation of the record is successful but without its IP, neither TTL.
My template is below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "DNSZoneName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "privatelink.database.windows.net",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the DNS zone. Must have at least 2 segements, e.g. hostname.org"
      }
    },
    "newRecordName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "pe-sql3",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the DNS record to be created. The name is relative to the zone, not the FQDN."
      }
    }
  },

  "resources": [
    {

      "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/A",
      "apiVersion": "2018-09-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('DNSZoneName'), '/', parameters('newRecordName'))]",
      "location": "global",
      "properties": {
        "TTL": 3600,
        "ARecords": [
          {
            "ipv4Address": "10.0.0.1"
          }
        ]
      }
    }

  ]
}
```

My command is `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName myRg -TemplateFile deploy.json`

Here is the screenshot of the A record from the portal:
[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was writing TTL and ARecords in capital letter. That should have been with **ttl** and **aRecords**:

```
    "properties": {
        "ttl": 3600,
        "aRecords": [
            {
                "ipv4Address": "1.2.3.4"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But the thing is that when it is written with capital letters, the REST API doesn’t throw error and accept the request. Normally, it should return http 400 error.

Anyway, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a race condition. Add a **dpendsOn**.

```
  "dependsOn": [
    "[parameters('DNSZoneName')]"
  ],
```

Like this:
[EDIT: specify the DNS Zone resource as well]

```
"resources": [
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones",
  "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
  "name": "[parameters('DNSZoneName')]",
  "location": "global"
},
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/A",
    "apiVersion": "2018-09-01",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('DNSZoneName'), '/', parameters('newRecordName'))]",
    "location": "global",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[parameters('DNSZoneName')]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "TTL": 3600,
        "ARecords": [
          {
            "ipv4Address": "10.0.0.1"
          }
        ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: When i add it, i get this error: New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: 7:06:24 AM - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The template reference 'privatelink.database.windows.net' is not valid: could not find template resource or resource copy with this name. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#reference for usage details.'.

Comment: @MoonHorse The error message means that there is no resource definition for **DNSZoneName**. I updated my answer to include one.

Comment: I have already tried that. Same result. It creates a record without IP and TLS configuration